# Google Tag Manager Custom HTML Page View URL Equals Trigger not Working

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, google-tag-manager, json-ld

I've just started using Tag Manager combined with Schema JSON-LD for the first time. I am attempting to use [Custom HTML](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107167?hl=en) but have hit a brick wall when attempting to assign Custom HTML to a URL based on Page View.

*I'm using the following custom html:*

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "ProfessionalService",
    "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Web_design",
    "name": "BYBE",
    "description": "The Web Design Company",
    "telephone": "01202 949749",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "Flat 11, East Cliff Grange, 35 Knyveton Road",
      "addressLocality": "Bournemouth",
      "addressRegion": "Dorset",
      "postalCode":"BH1 3QJ"
    },
    "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "50.73744",
    "longitude": "-1.8495269"
    }
  }
</script>
```

*Which I can confirm works when testing it with [Google's Rich Snippet Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=bybe.net):*

[image: BYBE SCHEMA JSON-LD TAG MANAGER]

*This works fine with:*

- Tag Type `Custom HTML`

  - Trigger Type `All Pages Page View`

*However it does not work with any of the following configurations:*

- Tag Type `Custom HTML`

  - Trigger Type `Page View` > `The trigger fires on:`

    1. `Page URL` > `equals` > `bybe.net/about`
    2. `Page URL` > `equals` > `bybe.net/about/`
    3. `Page URL` > `equals` > `www.bybe.net/about`
    4. `Page URL` > `equals` > `www.bybe.net/about/`

As you can see from above I have tried plenty of different URL types and its not clear what Google is expecting, Googles own examples does not use `HTTP` `HTTPS` or with `WWW` so I'm not sure why this is not working, hopefully someone can assist pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page URL` is full url (including protocol) , try contains instead of equals.
[image]

Ref : https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106965?hl=en

To check value of each built-in variable's on your page follow below listed steps :

**1.** Enabling `Preview & Debug` mode on your GTM web container

[image]

**2.** Open your website, you'll see a `Quick Preview` panel on bottom of your website.

**3.** Go to the event (Window Loaded/DOM Ready/Page View) you want your variable on and then navigate to variables tab, there you'll find all user-defined and built-in variables. Search for the variable you're looking for and there you'll find it's value listed.

[image]