# Google Tag Manager Multiple URL Exceptions not Working

Tags: schema.org, google-tag-manager, json-ld

I am using Google Tag Manager to insert [my Schema JSON-LD](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100429/google-tag-manager-custom-html-page-view-url-equals-trigger-not-working) data and as my schema data is presented in the footer it makes sense to use the following:

- Tag Type > `Custom HTML`

  - Trigger Type > `All Pages Page View`

*However... I have two pages with no footer:*

- `https://www.bybe.net/contact-us/`
- `https://www.bybe.net/services/`

*So my initial thoughts were to simply add a couple exceptions filter to the trigger like so:*

[image: Google Tag Manager URL Exceptions]

So using the above Page URL exceptions filters does not work, however... using one exception rule works absolutely fine.

*Question(s):*

- Why is multiple exceptions not working when using one filter does?
- How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When adding exception operations, there's a note above it:
*Fire this trigger when an Event occurs and all of these conditions are true*

You'll need to create two separate rules, each containing just onePage URL operation. Then add both rules to the list of exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Yhorian](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/61597/yhorian) for pointing me in the right direction. This issue occurs when adding multiple rule sets within one exception. When using multiple URL paths you need to ensure that you are using multiple exceptions, each with their own set of rules.

*Your Google Tag Manager Trigger Configuration should look something like this:*

[image: Google Tag Manager URL Exceptions]